# change the bits order

Tags: java, android, hex, bit

I have a function that converts an int into a hex. In this function, i get a seekbar's value between 0 and 100. Then I do some changes and finally i convert it to hex.

```
    private String decimalToHex(int i) {

    /**Conversion to decimal of the seekbar's % value*/
    int_value = ((i * 20480) / 100) * -1;
    int_value = -20480 - int_value;

    /**Conversion to hex*/
    hex_value = Integer.toString(int_value, 16);
    //hex_value = Integer.toHexString(c2_final);

    return hex_value;
}
```

Lets suppose that the `int i` value is 52. this gets the next value: `int_value = -9831`

When I convert this value into hex, i get `-2667`. But this is not the value I need.

I need to make a conversion that gives me as the hex result a value like "D999". 
I get this value by ones-complementing the value (aka the `~` operator).
This would be something like converting the value `-9831` to positve `9831`, then substracting 1 to get `9830`, and the last, changing the bits to get the value `55705` that in hex would be `D999`.

How can I do this last thing? change the bits?

Code in C:

```
if (int_value < 0) {

        c2_value = int_value * -1;
        c2_value = c2_value - 1;
        c2_final = ~c2_value;
    }
```

Comment: `-9831` **is** `-2667` in hexadecimal. It's unclear what you're asking or how you would get some magic `55705` / `D999` from that.

Comment: I just added the code on the previous post. I need the values to be the same, so If he gets that, i need to get that. When he does this `c2_final = ~c2_value;` he passes the 9830 value into 55705. When i do it, I get the 9830 value back to -9380. I think he is just converting a signed value to a unsigned one or something else.

Comment: Have you tried my code provided in answer?

Comment: answered under your answer @Chintan Rathod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.Integer` provides [toHexString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29) method which converts the specified integer into its hexadecimal string representation.

You can use like following.

```
Log.d(TAG, java.lang.Integer.toHexString(-9831));
```

This will give you output

```
08-07 18:53:57.643: D/Home(31698): ffffd999
```

to get your output, use following code.

```
String strHex = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(-9831);
if (strHex.length() > 4)
    Log.d(TAG, strHex.substring(4));
else
    Log.d(TAG, strHex);
```

Comment: That is what I first was doing, but I get this extra byte `ffff` that I don't need

Comment: @masmic_87, Okay. Do you know `-` will convert all code binary field to `1`? Its once complement. I am editing my code. Just try it.

Comment: Ok @Chintan Rathod, but i think that this example is the same that the first. i mean, as I understanded, i do this `Integer.toHexString(-9831)` to get this `ffffd999`. What I need after doing this, is to get only the last 2 bytes, this is, the d999 value. How can i do this?

Comment: @masmic_87, Simple. Use `outputString.substring(4)`. This will give you output `d999`. :)

Comment: You mean something like: `hex_value_full = Integer.toHexString(-9831);
        hex_value = outputString.hex_value_full(4)`?? I get a error "outpuString cannot be resolved" when doing this.

Comment: no no.. you are doing wrong...try `hex_value_full = Integer.toHexString(-9831).substring(4);`. This will return `d999`. This method might fire `OutOfIndexException`. I am editing my answer to tackle this :)

Comment: jajaja, Ok thanks @Chintan Rathod!! my fault! just understanded the wrong way! It's doing it right this way!